# How to redirect only android+china user with Branchio?

Tags: node.js, branch.io

We are using Branchio. We have deepview templates defined in Dashboard for Desktop, Ios, Android. Today all is working fine. Android users are redirected after clicking on our deepview button to Play Store.

Now we want our China location based user to be redirected to another page/deepview. I have read I can use `$fallback_url_cn` to make a fallback url for China only. But to use this property, I have to user `$fallback_url` also... But I want only China user to be redirected...

We are using the nodejs sdk. In the doc they are talking about `Fallback overrides (ordered by precedence)`, which doesn't make any sense in a js object.

Here is the confs I tried

```
 const linkData = {
       data: {
           deeplink,
           'custom_bool': true,
           '$og_title': stripedTagogTitle,
           '$og_description':stripedTagogDescription,
           '$og_image_url':picture,
           "$ios_deepview":"deepview_prc",
           "$fallback_url_cn" : environment.links.chinaStores,
           "$android_deepview":"deepview_prc",
           "$desktop_deepview":"deepview_prc",
           "$fallback_url" : environment.links.chinaStores,
       }
   };

   branchioClient.link(linkData)
```

But I would have like to write something like:

```
 const linkData = {
       data: {
           deeplink,
           'custom_bool': true,
           '$og_title': stripedTagogTitle,
           '$og_description':stripedTagogDescription,
           '$og_image_url':picture,
           "$fallback_url_cn" : environment.links.chinaStores,
                }
   };

   branchioClient.link(linkData)
```

So far, it is not working. Any help?

Comment: Can you please share which SDK version you're using?

Comment: "branchio-sdk": "^1.1.1",

Comment: Should I use the api directly?

Answer (score 0):

Personally suggest use `$fallback_url` to land in a middle page. Then, redirect users from the middle page to final page.

reason:

- it is flexible
- have more control
- easy to update the final page url